# Convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to search for convergence of the series 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+3}$.
I tried to do this by ratio and root test, but unfortunately both are one.
I already found out that it is divergent.
So I tried to show this by comparison test.
I wanted do to this by the estimation that
$\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+3}\ge \frac{1}{n+3} $, but obviously that didn't help.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Why didn't that help? It should settle the matter.

Comment: Note that if $n\gt 0$ then $\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+3}\gt \frac{n}{n^2+2n^2+3n^2}=\frac{1}{6n}$. Or else do a limit comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I am just aware that $\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, but this means not that $\frac{1}{n+3}$ is divergent, or am I wrong?

Comment: @SR23 You are wrong, if $\sum\frac1n$ diverges, then $\sum\frac1{n+3}$ also diverges.  Anything of the form $\sum\frac1{an+b}$ diverges, and more generally, $\sum\frac{an+b}{pn^2+qn+r}$ diverges.

Comment: The series for $\frac{1}{n+3}$ is the same series as for $\frac{1}{n}$, you're just starting a little later ($\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+3}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $$\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+3}> \frac{n+1}{n^2+4n+3}=\frac{n+1}{(n+1)(n+3)}=\frac1{n+3}, $$
and $\sum_n \frac1{n+3}$ does not converge (by integral test or limit comparison with $\sum_n\frac1n$). It follows by basic comparison test that $\sum_n \frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+3}$ does not converge.

Comment: Oh, just beat me to it.  I guess I'll slink off and delete mine... :-)

Comment: @BrianTung Just find some other way to prove that the series doesn't converge :)

Comment: Hahaha, maybe, if I find a very entertaining way... :-P

Answer (score 5):

Direct comparison should work here, but you may also use the **limit comparison test.** Given two series $S_{a}$ and $S_{b},$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_{b}}{S_{a}} > 0$ and exists, then they are either both diverging or converging. Let us compare
$$S_{a} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{n + 1}{n^{2} + 2n + 3}$$
with the series
$$S_{b} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}.$$

By the limit comparison test,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_{b}}{S_{a}}$$
$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2} + 2n + 3}{n^{2} + n}$$
$$= 1 > 0.$$

So since $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, the original series also **diverges.**

Answer (score 2):

let $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}$. This function is continues, positive and decreasing in $[1,+\infty)$, so we can calculate following integral instead of convergence of the series.
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+2x+3)\mathcal{|_{1}^{+\infty}}\to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

You can try finding whether
$$
\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+3}\ge\frac{1}{n+a}
$$
holds for $n$ sufficiently large, where $a>1$. This becomes
$$
n^2+(a+1)n+a\ge n^2+2n+3
$$
so
$$
n\ge\frac{3-a}{a-1}
$$
You see that taking $a\ge3$ is good.